# How to use defined function in functional API keras

Tags: tensorflow, lambda, functional-programming, layer

I'm super confusing with lambda layer during functional API
please tell me which is correct

For example

```
def magic(x):
   x2=x+x
   return x2

D = Input((n,))
E = Lambda(magic)(D)
d = Model(~~~~) 

or

D = Input((n,))
E = magic(D)
d = Model(~~~~)
```

and another case

```
def magic():
   x2=np.randn(3,1)
   return x2

D = Input((n,))
E = Lambda(magic)
d = Model(~~~~) 

or

D = Input((n,))
E = magic()
d = Model(~~~~)
```

please save me !!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the first way if you want to wrap your custom operation as a Layer like follows

```
def magic(x):
    x2 = x + x
    return x2

inp = tf.keras.Input(shape=(2,))
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, name="id_1")(inp)

# Ways to Define Custom Layer
x = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda val: magic(val))(x)
# or
# x = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(magic)(x)
# or
# x = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda val: (val + val))(x)

x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, name="id_2")(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inp, outputs=x, name="inner_model")

print(model.summary())
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have a question one more. how can the function without input be used with the lambda layer??? It means the second black box in my question

Comment: In second case, i believe the output of your magic function would be used somewhere with another (custom) layer. if yes, i don't think you need an additional layer for that. For example you can perform a linear transformation `y=mx+c` in a sigle Lambda layer. That means you don't need two lambda layers, such as: one for multiplication and another for addition with random salt from second magic function.